# SQL SERVER CONVERT DATETIME EN VISTA

Tags: sql, server

> Estimados: Tengo una tabla en donde tengo varios campos de fecha pero en formato Nvarchar,  los tengo en ese formato por motivos de calculos.
> Paralelamente, Para que me los muestre en el formato correcto se me ocurrió generar una vista y así consultarla y no tener que convertir el campo cada vez que lo necesite ver y puedo seguir manteniendo el formato Nvarchar en la tabla.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ULTIMA_TABLA
CREATE VIEW ULTIMA_TABLA
AS
select 
campo1 as 1
,campo2 as 2
,FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),[fechanac])),''dd/MM/yyyy'') as FECHA_NACIMIENTO
from base.dbo.tabla
```

> Le ejecución del script sin problemas.

> La sentencia la verifiqué y funciona para un select de una tabla, pero cuando realizo un select de la vista aparece el siguiente mensaje

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

> Gracias.

Comment: Qué versión de SQLServer? Intenta usar esta query para encontrar cuál(es) dato(s) puede(n) estar tirando el error. `SELECT fechanac AS InvalidDate 
FROM dbo.tabla WHERE fechanac IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(date, fechanac, 103) IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual pegas el código, y a priori el problema esta en la sintaxis de la creación de la vista.

Para el escenario que planteas, cambiando un poquito los nombres de la tabla.

```
Drop table if exists dbo.La_Tabla;

Create table dbo.La_Tabla(fechanac nvarchar(100), campo1 varchar(1), campo2 varchar(1));
Go
Insert into dbo.La_Tabla(fechanac)
values
('20210101'),
('20210201'),
('20210301'),
('20210401');
GO
```

La posible solución:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.ULTIMA_TABLA;
go
CREATE VIEW dbo.ULTIMA_TABLA
AS
select 
campo1 as [1]
,campo2 as [2]
,FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),[fechanac])),'dd/MM/yyyy') as FECHA_NACIMIENTO
from dbo.La_Tabla
go
```

En el código, se ven dos problemas.

1. Las columnas con alias numérico
2. El doble apóstrofe en el parámetro de la función Format

   Select * from dbo.ULTIMA_TABLA;

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Como comentario adicional, el hecho que indicas, de los tengo de este tipo por motivos de cálculo, quizá deberías de darle una nueva pensada, ya que precisamente, los cálculos en columnas de tipo texto (varchar/nvarchar), no son precisamente, ni óptimos, ni exentos de problemáticas adicionales.